# can i debug with real tablet when using eclipse inside vmware

Tags: android, debugging, virtual-machine

Is it possible to debug with my real tablet device when my eclipse Android Development Tools development environment is in VMware?

Comment: Yes, you may. Simply link your tablet device to vmware and your emulated operating system will detect a new device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You have to plug in your device **and don't forget to install the appropriate driver of your device** and it will be detected automatically